# Curly brackets catching many lines in tables

Tags: tables, brackets

I have the following table

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  
\hline
 \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Bosonic spectrum of type IIA and IIB theories} \\
 \hline
 Sector& IIA & IIB\\
 \hline
  NS-NS  & graviton  $g_{\mu \nu}$   & graviton $g_{\mu \nu}$ \\
NS-NS &  dilaton $\phi$  & dilaton $\phi$\\ \hline
R-R & 1-form  $C_1$& (axion)0-form $C_0$\\
R-R   &3-form $C_3$ & 2-form $C_2$ \\
R-R &    & (self-dual) 4-form $C_4$\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

which I do not know how to make it appear (how do I Latex in this forum?). I would like to do something so that the first column which has these NS-NS and R-R entries to be such that there is only one entry since the first three columns correspond all to NS-NS and the last three all correspond to R-$. That is I would like the first entry of the first column for the first three lines to be something like R{ (so the curly bracket to include all first three columns) and similarly for the last three ones.

How could I do this?

[image]

Comment: I'm finding it a little difficult to follow your description- you refer to six different columns but your table only has three. Could you draw a sketch of what you want the table to look like? MS Paint will do.

Comment: @NatalieHogg: I have the impression that the O.P. is after `\multirow`

Comment: How can I write tex here? Like in math mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |R{2cm}||p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Bosonic spectrum of type IIA and IIB theories} \\
\hline
Sector& IIA & IIB\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{NS-NS $\begin{dcases*} \\ \\ \end{dcases*}$}  & graviton  $g_{\mu \nu}$   & graviton $g_{\mu \nu}$ \\
&  dilaton $\phi$  & dilaton $\phi$\\[1.5ex]
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{R-R $\begin{dcases} \\ \\ \\ \end{dcases}$} & 1-form  $C_1$& (axion)0-form $C_0$\\
&3-form $C_3$ & 2-form $C_2$ \\
&    & (self-dual) 4-form $C_4$\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes exactly like this. Thanks a lot, it seems quite a work to do this!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ |p{3cm}||p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
 \Block{1-3}{Bosonic spectrum of type IIA and IIB theories} \\
 \hline
 Sector& IIA & IIB\\
 \hline
\Block{2-1}{NS-NS}  & graviton  $g_{\mu \nu}$   & graviton $g_{\mu \nu}$ \\
         &  dilaton $\phi$  & dilaton $\phi$\\ \hline
\Block{3-1}{R-R}& 1-form  $C_1$& (axion)0-form $C_0$\\
& 3-form $C_3$ & 2-form $C_2$ \\
&               & (self-dual) 4-form $C_4$\\
 \hline
\CodeAfter
   \SubMatrix{\{}{3-2}{4-2}{.}[xshift=8mm,extra-height=-1.5mm]
   \SubMatrix{\{}{5-2}{7-2}{.}[xshift=8mm,extra-height=-1mm]
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]